# Did R.C Sproul consider any historical-seeming book to be non-historical?

Tags: exegesis, reformed-theology, rc-sproul

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWZHL_MoDvY) on YouTube by R.C. Sproul and it discussed the Sensus Literalis, and how genre matters. One comment that surpised me was that, Sproul says it may take a lot of technical work to work out what the genre a book is in.

The example that he uses for this is Jonah. Sproul discusses how this has elements of fable or elements of poetry, but then he comes down onto the bog-standard historical position. Are there any books that seem historical where Sproul did not come down onto the historical position?

Job is the obvious candidate, but I haven't been able to find anything on it.